# How can I export the values in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file called `env.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=******
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=******
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
```

I have the original script file `test.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source env.sh

echo -n "Enter the Environment name you wish to choose [test|test1]: "
read env

case $env in

  test)
      export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
     echo "The values of ${env} are exported"
    ;;

  test1)
     export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
     echo "The values of ${env} are exported"
     ;;
  *)
    echo "***testing**"
   
    ;;
esac
```

It looks like the script is running in a child process. Is there a way to export the values?

Comment: if you do not want to be ran in a child process, you need to use the command 'source' as you did for the env.sh; by default, any script is executed in a subshell.

Comment: Thank you for info. But qucik question How can i export these values in the subshell ?

Comment: When you want to use the new settings, don't do `./test.sh; ./my_aws_script.sh`, that won;t help. You need `source ./test.sh; ./my_aws_script.sh`.

Comment: c.f. https://ss64.com/bash/source.html

Comment: You might want to consider using the standard aws config and then use an AWS_PROFILE var instead. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html. Heres how I switch around https://github.com/sanguis/.sanguis_settings/blob/master/zshrc#L162

Comment: @WalterA Thank you for your help !! I appriciate it sir it worked

Comment: You cannot pass environment variables from child process to parent.

Comment: @Kalyan : _It looks like the script is running in a child process_ You did not specify, **how** you executed this script, so, technically speaking, this can't be answered.